# Find $Var(XY)$ for $X,Y$ chosen from a unit square.

Tags: probability, variance

Let $(X, Y)$ be a point chosen at random on the unit square $[0, 1] × [0, 1]$. Find $Var[XY]$.

**My Attempt** (I think I have the right answer. I just want some verification. Thank you)

First, we want to find the c.d.f. so we can find the p.d.f.

The c.d.f. is
$$
F_{X,Y}(x,y)=
\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if } x\leq 0, y\leq 0\\
xy & \text{if } 0<x\leq 1, 0<y\leq 1\\
1 & \text{if } x>1,y>1
\end{cases}
$$
Then the joint p.m.f. is
$$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=1\quad \text{for } 0<x\leq 1,0<y\leq 1$$
Integrating with respects to $y$ gives the p.d.f.for $X$, and with respects to $x$ for $Y$. So
$$f_X(x)=
\begin{cases}
1 &\text{if }0<x\leq 1\\
0 &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
$$f_Y(y)=
\begin{cases}
1 &\text{if }0<y\leq 1\\
0 &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
It is clear that the marginal mean is $\mathbb{E}[X]=\mathbb{E}[Y]=\frac{1}{2}$. Since the joint p.d.f. is the product of the marginals, we know that they are independent, so the expectation of $XY$ is the product of their marginal expectations:
$$\mathbb{E}[XY]=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{4}$$
Now we need to find $\mathbb{E}[(XY)^2]$.
$$\mathbb{E}[(XY)^2]=\int^1_0\int^1_0(xy)^2dxdy=\frac{1}{9}$$
Using the definition of variance, we have
$$Var(XY)=\mathbb{E}[(XY)^2]-\mathbb{E}[XY]^2=\frac{1}{9}-\frac{1}{16}=\frac{7}{144}$$

Comment: Sounds correct!

Comment: One thing though, the C.D.F. is: $$F_{X,Y}(x,y) = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{if } x\leq 0~\text{ or }~y\leq 0\\ xy & \text{if } 0<x\leq 1, 0<y\leq 1\\ x &\text{if }0<x\leq 1< y\\ y &\text{if } 0<y\leq 1< x\\ 1 & \text{if } 1<x, 1<y\end{cases}$$

Comment: @GrahamKemp Why do we have to include the $x$ for $0<x\leq 1<y$ and $y$ for $0<y\leq 1<x$? Aren't those values out of the range that we are looking at?

Comment: @JamesAnderson So too is the range $1<x, 1<y$ outside the support of the pdf.  We include those partitions so that the **joint CDF**, $F_{\small X,Y}(x,y)$, is defined for all real values of the arguments, as it should be.

Comment: After all, the cumulative probability $\mathsf P(X\leqslant 1/2, Y\leqslant 2)$ can be evaluated.  It equals $1/2$.  So $F_{\small X,Y}(1/2, 2)$ needs to do so too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My Attempt (I think I have the right answer. I just want some verification. Thank you)

Verified.  You have the right answer.  All your work checks out, and in short, since the variables are independent and identically uniformly distributed over $(0..1)$ then:...

$$\begin{align}\mathsf {Var}(XY) &=\mathsf E(X^2)\mathsf E(Y^2)-\mathsf E(X)^2\mathsf E(Y)^2 \\ &= \left(\int_0^1 s^2\mathrm ds\right)^2-\left(\int_0^1 s\mathrm d s\right)^4\\ &= \left(\dfrac 13\right)^2-\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^4\\&=\dfrac{2^4-3^2}{3^22^4}\\&=\dfrac{7}{144}\end{align}$$